# mysqli data fetch using explode no result getting

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, explode

From table, i am fetching $rows['colorVariants']; but its value i am getting like:-

[JEADV9Q23ESG25HY,JEADV9Q2NFRNYV5Q,JEADV9Q2PNBTXGNX,JEADV9Q2XKWPXWSX,JEADY8ABWH9XNF4B,JEADZWEBDHWRJ2NQ,JEADZWEBRWZ4B4VS,JEADZWEBXDCGSYCF,JEAEYYX95YYC4DRA]

Then i used substr to remove square bracket.

Explode this value and again need to fetch it it the same table for similar products, but i am not getting any result.

```
<?php
$table = table1; // Table Name
$mysqli = mysqli connection // Mysqli Connection here

$result = $mysqli->query( "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE `id` = '$q' ");
while ( $rows =  $result->fetch_assoc() ) {

$rows['colorVariants'] = [JEADV9Q23ESG25HY,JEADV9Q2NFRNYV5Q,JEADV9Q2PNBTXGNX,JEADV9Q2XKWPXWSX,JEADY8ABWH9XNF4B,JEADZWEBDHWRJ2NQ,JEADZWEBRWZ4B4VS,JEADZWEBXDCGSYCF,JEAEYYX95YYC4DRA] // Result Copy Sample

// substr using for remove square bracket
$colorVariants = substr($rows['colorVariants'], 1);
$newColorVariants = substr($colorVariants, 0, '-1');
$finalColorVariants = explode(',', $newColorVariants);
}
?>

<?php
for($i = 0; $i < count($finalColorVariants); $i++) {
$color = $finalColorVariants[$i];
$color = $mysqli->real_escape_string($color);

$colorVariants = $mysqli->query( "SELECT id,store,title,imageUrlStr,mrp,price,productBrand FROM $table_name WHERE `productId` = '".$color."' ");
if ($colorVariants) {
while ($rows = $colorVariants->fetch_assoc()) { 
$id1 = $rows['id'];
$store1 = $rows['store'];
$title1 = $rows['title'];
$imageUrlStr1 = $rows['imageUrlStr'];
$mrp1 = $rows['mrp'];
$price1 = $rows['price'];
$productBrand1 = $rows['productBrand'];

}

?>
            <div class="cloth-inner-similar-box">
                <div class="cloth-inner-similar-boxin">
                <a href="clothing?q=<?php echo $id1; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $imageUrlStr1; ?>" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="cloth-inner-similar-boxin-offer">
                    <div class="cloth-inner-similar-boxin-offer-in">
                    <p>30% OFF</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="cloth-inner-similar-boxin-head">
                    <a href="clothing?q=<?php echo $id1; ?>"><?php echo $title1; ?></a>
                </div>
                <div class="cloth-inner-similar-price border-solid-bottom border-solid-top">
                <a href="clothing?q=<?php echo $id1; ?>">Best Buy  &#64; <?php echo $price1; ?>/-</a><a href="<?php echo $id1; ?>" class="href"><?php echo $productBrand1; ?></a>
                </div>

                </div>
<?php
} }
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: is :
SELECT id,store,title,imageUrlStr,mrp,price,productBrand FROM table_name WHERE `productId` = 'JEADV9Q23ESG25HY';
SELECT id,store,title,imageUrlStr,mrp,price,productBrand FROM table_name WHERE `productId` = 'JEADV9Q2NFRNYV5Q'; 
returning any results when directly run in MySql ?

Comment: yes i am getting result on JEADV9Q2NFRNYV5Q

Comment: hmmm.... can you echo the dynamic SQL you are creating and try to run that in MySql and also echo "$colorVariants" variable ?

Comment: Yes its dynamic sql every time query will change and also $colorVariants codes are changed.

Comment: I am saying :
$sql = "SELECT id,store,title,imageUrlStr,mrp,price,productBrand FROM $table_name WHERE `productId` = '".$color." ' ";
$colorVariants = $mysqli->query($sql);
echo 'SQL : '. $sql;
print_r($colorVariants);
echo '<br/>';

Comment: i got result like this **SQL : SELECT id,store,title,imageUrlStr,mrp,price,productBrand FROM flipkart3 WHERE `productId` = 'JEADV9Q23ESG25HY' mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 7 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 0 [type] => 0 ) **

Comment: that's interesting, you are saying "SELECT id,store,title,imageUrlStr,mrp,price,productBrand FROM flipkart3 WHERE productId = 'JEADV9Q23ESG25HY' " gives you result when directly run in mysql however mysqli_result Object giving 0 row.

Comment: I am not understanding how to solve this problem.

Comment: can you upload your database records and share via Dropbox or something

Comment: Which type of record you need for reference ?

Comment: flipcart3 table schema along with 10-15 records

Comment: Please check this attached [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yi6tffjrru93wmc/flipkart3.ods?dl=0)

Comment: I got it. When you are storing colorVariants in table, you are adding a space before each item starting from 2nd index.  
For example : [BRAE72HGHETGFTYT, BRAE72HGTMYQTFHW, BRAE72HGWKCNZ9VP, BRAE72HGWZBAGHB2]. And when "$color" variable is getting initialized it it initialized with with values beginning with a space i.e. $color = ' BRAE72HGTMYQTFHW'; 

Since this blank space is not there in productid column, the query returns 0 rows. And this is true for all colorVariants starting from 2nd index. 

Use : $color = trim($mysqli->real_escape_string($color)); to negate the effect of blank space.

Comment: tested with $q='1143734' and it worked for me.

Comment: did that solution worked ?

Comment: After editing i am getting this type of result **SQL : SELECT id,store,title,imageUrlStr,mrp,price,productBrand FROM flipkart3 WHERE `productId` = 'JEADV9Q2NFRNYV5Q' mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 7 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 )** no item are displayed.

Comment: did my suggestion helped you ? if yes, can you please mark comment as usefull.

Comment: Yes your suggestion is useful for thank you so much. @joyd